# Windows hooks question

Tags: windows, events, hook, monitor

We have a legacy program written by a third party company and I need to capture screen data when the user clicks a button on that application. Now, I can capture the text using SendMessage() with the WM_GETTEXT parameter. The only problem is that I need to do this when the user clicks the 'Submit' button.

I created a DLL and used the SetWindowsHookEx() to capture the mouse events to the application  and I get the mouse click notifications. The only problem is that I don't know where they clicked in the application.

Can someone point me in the correct direction to capture the button click notifications in a different application?

Thanks in advance.

Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xPos = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam); 
yPos = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645607%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

The coordinate is relative to the upper-left corner of the client area.
The `ChildWindowFromPoint` API might be of some use to you too.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632676%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I used WindowFromPoint() and it gave me what I wanted.